# I want to make a button that rotates itself after click

Tags: javascript, css, button, rotation, show-hide

I want to to make a button that rotates itself after click. The button has a dynamic name (id, class). When clicked it shows or hides a part of a wordpress post. When post is unwrapped I want it to point upwards, when wrapped downwards.

```
<div>
    <div class="button_wrap" id="opis<?php echo get_the_ID()?>"> <button class="button" type="button" id="button<?php echo get_the_ID()?>"></button> </div>
</div>
<script>
    $("#button<?php echo get_the_ID()?>").click(function() {
        $("#opis<?php echo get_the_ID()?>").slideToggle(1000);
    });
</script>
```

CSS

```
.button_wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
}
.button {
    background: url(/arrow.svg) no-repeat;
    margin-top: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 50px;
    width: 75px;
    border: none;
    transition: .3s ease;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.button:hover {
    background: url(/arrow.svg) no-repeat;
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 50px;
    width: 75px;
    border: none;
    transition: .3s ease;
    margin-top: 13px;
}
.opisy {
    display: none;
}
```

I believe that I have to add a css class to the button but then I have to remove it after the second click. I got a bit lost, maybe there's a simpler way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest method imo.

```js
$('.btn').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('rotate');
});
```

```css
.btn {
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
}

.rotate {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='btn'>content</button>
```

Comment: It does work but I have a strange bug where only every other button rotates.

Comment: @Tad Describe that bug.

Comment: There's a loop displaying wordpress posts and in that loop i have an id  using the post id ( id="button<?php echo get_the_ID()?>" )to target the buttons and posts. The button shows hidden content of the post. Maybe there's a way of further isolating the script?

Comment: I changes the class to an id used in the previous function. Now the script looks like this :     $("#button<?php echo get_the_ID()?>").click(function(){ $(this).toggleClass('rotate');   });   Thank you for the help! :)

Comment: @Tad My pleasure, have a great day!